# Foreach statement in C#, but except the row from the current selected item?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an edit part in my c# WPF application (bowling reservation application). I first choose a reservation and then load all the information into the window. Then I can edit some information and click Edit. On the Edit button there is a query which checks if the edited time is available (or not).

But my code says of course Not, because I have a foreach loop where all reservations go through, also the current edited row. So my question is; can I except this row from my foreach loop?

Edit button:

```
// Get selected artist
var selRes = ((Reservation)epl.cbxRes.SelectedItem).Id;

var bowlingav = from reservation in db.reservation
                 where reservation.cus_id == selRes
                 select performance;

foreach (reservation rr in bowlingav)
{
    var sql = from r in db.reservations
              where rr.end_time < theEndTimeChosen
              select r;
}
```

So in the foreach loop there will be a record which is the current edited row and I want to exclude this one from the query.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: They are both good. Do I need to choose one then ?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes you can accept only one of the answers. Accept the one that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `Id` of the "reservation" before defining your SQL.

```
 foreach (reservation rr in bowlingav)
 {
    if(rr.Id != selRes) //As far as I understood you want to exclude the row with id = selRes
    {
      var sql = from r in db.reservations
      where rr.end_time < theEndTimeChosen
      select r;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood, but have you tried this ? :

**EDIT :** reading the code again, I'm not sure what you want to do with the bowlingNav since you select Reservation Id that matches with customre ID ??
+ you shouldn't write query in a foreach loop in my opinion

```
foreach (reservation rr in bowlingav)
{
  var sql = from r in db.reservations
            where rr.Id != r.Id
                  && rr.end_time < theEndTimeChosen
            select r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have an unique ID for every reservation so you could just exclude the selected reservation in your foreach-loop:

```
foreach (reservation rr in bowlingav)
{
    if(rr.id != selRes)
    {
        var sql = from r in db.reservations
                  where rr.end_time < theEndTimeChosen
                  select r;
    }
}
```